# Python Multithreading in a class method

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, class, thread-safety

The current code:

```
my_dictionary = {}

class Test:
    def fun1(self, arg1):
        #...some code
        my_dictionary[arg1] = "some_value"
    
    def fun2(self):
        arg_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
        threads = []
        for arg_val in arg_list:
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.fun1, args=(arg_val,))
            threads.append(t)

        for thread in threads: thread.start()
        for thread in threads: thread.join()
```

and causing `operation timed out` error while running `fun2`

I'm new to Python so i dont really know as to what's going on

Comment: You are defining your methods without the `self` argument, but you are trying to use `self` -> `self.fun1`.

Comment: @Mark thanks for pointing it out. Will make an edit

Answer (score 0):

Try it with this funciton.

```
    def fun2(self):
            // ^---------------------------------------------- Add ----.
        arg_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] //                 |           |
        threads = []                    //                 |           |
        for arg_val in arg_list:        //                 |           | 
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.fun1, args=[arg_val] daemon=True)
            threads.append(t)

        for thread in threads: thread.start()
        for thread in threads: thread.join()
```

Comment: Same error, `socket.timeout: The read operation timed out`